# How to change the frame/buffer size on a Spring 5 webflux websocket client

Tags: java, spring, websocket

My Spring 5 webflux websocket client is throwing below Exception when  server sends large messages.
Can someone tell me how can I increase the frame size on the client?

```
Flux<String> input = Flux.just(StrJSON);

WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
client.execute(new URI(url),
      session ->  session
                  .send(input.map(session::textMessage))
                  .thenMany(
                      session.receive()
                            .map(t->t.getPayloadAsText())

                            .log()
                    )
                    .then()          
        ).block();
```

Intermittent Exception:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.    
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:277)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
 .....
```

Comment: @vindev please do not use blockquote for stack trace, it messes up the indentation and makes the stack trace unreadable.  Use code formatting for stack traces and error messages.

Comment: @JimGarrison Got it, Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You're welcome. The rest of your edit was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to help you.

According to this [merge request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/22367/files) you should set your client as type of `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` instead of the interface `WebSocketClient`.

Then you can call `client.setMaxFramePayloadLength(maxFramePayload);`

So in your code you should have:

```
ReactorNettyWebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
client.setMaxFramePayloadLength(2097152);

client.execute(new URI(url),
      session ->  session
                  .send(input.map(session::textMessage))
                  .thenMany(
                      session.receive()
                            .map(t->t.getPayloadAsText())

                            .log()
                    )
                    .then()          
        ).block();
```

Answer (score 0):

Response of @dazito has been deprecated since spring-webflux:5.3.

Use instead:

```
WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient(HttpClient.create(),
    () -> WebsocketClientSpec.builder().maxFramePayloadLength(524288000))
```

Source: [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/client/ReactorNettyWebSocketClient.html) (Deprecated.
as of 5.3 in favor of providing a supplier of WebsocketClientSpec.Builder with a constructor argument)